# Play framework, why does the installation script gives a python syntax error?

Tags: shell, playframework, syntax-error

I am trying to install the play framework following the instructions [instructions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Installing)
 however I had no success in executing the play script which is the installation file.

What I have done so far:

1. Installed open java so now both java -version and jaac -version work
2. Did `chmod a+x ./play` to give rights to the script, I even did `chmod a+x play-2.0.4` the whole directory
3. After having no success I discovered that the play script can be executed with this: python ./play

However I get this error:

```
  File "./play", line 4
    while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So my question is:
Why does this syntax error occur, it seems pretty impossible that the script could have a syntax error?

Just for reference, this is the whole script:

```
done
dir=`dirname $PRG`

if [ -f conf/application.conf ]; then
  if test "$1" = "clean-all"; then
    rm -rf target
    rm -rf tmp
    rm -rf logs
    rm -rf dist
    rm -rf project/project
    rm -rf project/target
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]
    then  
     shift
    else
      echo "[info] Done!"
      exit 0
    fi
  fi
  if test "$1" = "stop"; then
    if [ -f RUNNING_PID ]; then
      echo "[info] Stopping application (with PID `cat RUNNING_PID`)..."
      kill `cat RUNNING_PID`

      RESULT=$?

      if test "$RESULT" = 0; then
        echo "[info] Done!"
        exit 0
      else
        echo "[\033[31merror\033[0m] Failed ($RESULT)"
        exit $RESULT
      fi
    else
      echo "[\033[31merror\033[0m] No RUNNING_PID file. Is this application running?"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  if test "$1" = "debug"; then
    JPDA_PORT="9999"
    shift      
  fi

  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    JPDA_PORT="${JPDA_PORT}" $dir/framework/build "$@"
  else
    JPDA_PORT="${JPDA_PORT}" $dir/framework/build play
  fi

else
  java -Dsbt.ivy.home=$dir/repository -Dplay.home=$dir/framework -Dsbt.boot.properties=$dir/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties -jar $dir/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
fi
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where does python come into all this? This is not a python script.

Comment: Hello matijin.. sorry if am doing some big error, I am in linux just a few days. As for python I read that the script is a python script, so I supposed I can run it with python ./play (but I could be wrong)

Comment: This looks like a shell script to me; the instructions you linked to do not mention python at all. The fact that it doesn't work with python is no surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a shell script using Python, this'll never work.

Although Play version 1 used Python, version 2 has switched to using a shell script instead.

Comment: Thank you Martjin, it was good to know it is not a python script, it helped me focus elsewhere. After more than a day I found some solution in running the play for anyone interested: I had to move the folder to /home this allowed me to give permissions (right click->permissions->group[my name], Access: read and write) to the folder. Then I just executed ./play from within the folder scope. However ./play is not what the official recommendation.